# Simple substitution in a file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file `test` with the following contents

```
foo
bar
```

I want to replace `foo` with `bar`.

I run `perl -p -e 's/foo/bar/g' test` but nothing happens.

I'm sure this has been done before, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [man perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) - read about the `-i`.

Comment: See @jm666 comment. And use the optional (mandatory on some Mac OS) extension for backups, better safe than sorry.

Comment: Your code looks like it should have output on the console. At the very least it should show the unchanged input, but actually it should show "bar bar". This is a different phrasing for what @jm666 comments.

Comment: @SDonnelly: Your command looks correct; the modified file contents should be printed to the console. Are you sure *"nothing happens"*, or do you just mean the file isn't modified? If you want to write your output to a file then you may redirect the output on the command line with `perl -pe 's/foo/bar/' test > new_file`.

Comment: It is hard to imagine you have done anything to try and solve this extremely simple operation. Te only thing I have to add to the above is that you have not tried this on a Windows generated file?  If so, try using dos2unix first and then try your code again.

Comment: @grail: The substitution in the question can't be affected by the line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue to answer here.

#### File `test.txt`

```
foo
bar
```

### Shell command

```
$ perl -pe 's/foo/bar/g' test.txt
```

#### output

```
bar
bar
```

Comment: I think it was because I was using windows.